# Auth allow function not working for pages controller in cakephp v2.5

Tags: cakephp, authentication, redirect

I am having problem with allow() function for `pages` controller in my cakePhp app. I needed to show `home`,`about` etc pages and for that I added :

```
//$this->Auth->allow('*');
$this->Auth->allow('add', 'home', 'about', 'executive_committee', 'gallery', 'jpl', 'contact_us', 'test');
```

The above code did not helped me, so I try adding

```
public function beforeFilter() {
   $this->Auth->allow('home', 'about', 'executive_committee', 'gallery', 'jpl', 'contact_us');
}
```

in my `PagesController.php`. But that also did not worked and getting `You are not authorized to access that location.` error message !

Comment: what urls are you using to try and access these pages? does any other part of your site work?

Comment: I too have this issue, did you get any solution?

Comment: Are you call the `Auth` component ?

Answer (score 0):

pages controller has a method called display by default when you install cakephp. 
Then in it you should have $this->Auth->allow ('display '); inside your beforeFilter method.
you should have all your static pages such as 'add',
'home', 'about' in the app/view/pages folder.